# Odoo 10 : Create internal link into Html field

Tags: python, html, odoo, odoo-10

I want to create an internal link into my Html field.

The Html field is a table which will be generated by a method "canceled_progressbar", I want to refer each line (provider_order) to the corresponding record view, this is my code :

```py
@api.one
    def canceled_progressbar(self):
        if(self.state == 'done'):
            raise ValidationError("This purchase invoice is done.")
            return False
        else:
            if(self.provider_order_ids):
                total_price_canceled = 0
                po_canceled = '<div class="o_cannot_create">'
                po_canceled = '<div class="table-responsive">'
                po_canceled = '<table class="o_list_view table table-condensed table-striped">'
                po_canceled += '<thead>'
                po_canceled += '<tr>'
                po_canceled += '<th data-id="name" class="o_column_sortable">Provider Orders Names</th>'
                po_canceled += '<th data-id="product_id" class="o_column_sortable">Product Names</th>'
                po_canceled += '<th data-id="qte_total_unity" class="o_column_sortable">Qte Total</th>'
                po_canceled += '<th data-id="price" class="o_column_sortable">Price</th>'
                po_canceled += '</tr>'
                po_canceled += '</thead>'
                po_canceled += '<tfoot><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tfoot>'
                po_canceled += '<tbody>'
                for provider_order_id in self.provider_order_ids.ids:
                    provider_order = self.env['tjara.provider_order'].browse(provider_order_id) 
                    provider_order.state = 'done'
                    total_price_canceled += provider_order.price
                    po_canceled += '<tr>'
                    po_canceled += '<td data-field="name" class="o_form_uri o_form_field o_readonly">'+provider_order.id+'</td>'
                    po_canceled += '<td class="o_readonly">'+provider_order.product_id.name+'</td>'
                    po_canceled += '<td class="o_readonly">'+provider_order.qte_total_unity+'</td>'
                    po_canceled += '<td class="o_readonly">'+str(provider_order.price)+'</td>'
                    po_canceled += '</tr>'
                po_canceled += '</div></div>'
                self.write({
                    'state': 'canceled',
                    'po_canceled': po_canceled,
                    'total_price_canceled':total_price_canceled,
                    'provider_order_ids':False
                })
```

Is there any method to make each line refers to its record ? Like a href trick or any other solution ? Or should I try something else ?

```
po_canceled += '<td data-field="name" class="o_form_uri o_form_field o_readonly"><a href="ANYSTUFFHERE">'+provider_order.id+'</a></td>'
```

PS: I don't want to duplicate the many2one field into another one because I want to keep the constant values of the relation when the user click the button cancel without touching these values after changes.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you doing that? Try to adapt your needs to the Odoo framework. If not you could create a widget or modify some of the existing widgets. Maybe a one2many field is suited with what you want to do

Comment: @ChesuCR I want to keep the same values at instant X. It's possible to add another class in which I store my values and relate it to the two entity but a HTML field would be more efficient. 
I added a hyperlink by adding the following : 

`po_canceled += '<a href="/web?id='+str(provider_order.id)+'&model=tjara.provider_order#id='+str(provider_order.id)+'&view_type=form&model=tjara.provider_order">'+provider_order.name+'</a>'`

But this display just the record without the menu and the action.